# How to print ssh output in rust

Tags: rust, ssh

I am making an application a part of which it ssh into a server and runs some commands.

```rust
        let mut s= session.channel_new().unwrap();
        s.open_session().unwrap();
        s.request_exec(input.as_ref()).unwrap();
        s.send_eof().unwrap();
        
        //standard output
        let mut buf=Vec::new();
        s.stdout().read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();
        println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf));

        //error output
        let mut buf=Vec::new();
        s.stderr().read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();
        println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf));
```

this is what I have so far, but the problem am facing is that it returns terminal output in two different set, standard and error. by printing it like this I am losing the order of output from the ssh session. lets say i do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and if this has any errors, it'll first print all the stuff that went well and then the error. How can I fix to have a real time output from the ssh session like the one you get from a terminal?

using https://docs.rs/ssh/latest/ssh/ for ssh

---

Comment: From what I understand, you'd have to request a pty. Which doesn't seem to be possible with the `ssh` crate. The `ssh` crate is also 6 years abandonware, or so? This may be possible with the `ssh2` crate. (Btw, spawning a command locally has the same "[problem](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/a-terminal-case-of-linux)".)

Comment: @Caesar thank you for the response! I upgraded to `ssh2` but how do I achieve pty?